# Two Columns Auto Height Background Colour

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table, background-color

I'm probably missing something really simple here. I have two columns which keep the same height, depending on which div has more content inside of it, however the background colour does not extend on the shorter column; the columns change to a vertical layout when the display is smaller with the use of media queries. **How can I get the background colour of the left column to extend to the bottom of the div?**

```css
#pageContainer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #pageContainer p {
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    
    .sectionContainer {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
    }
    
    .leftColumn {
        display: table-cell;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #4F4F4F;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .rightColumn {
        display: table-cell;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        color: #000000;
        
    }
    
    @media all and (max-width: 768px) {    
        .sectionContainer {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .leftColumn {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .rightColumn {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="pageContainer">
  <div class="sectionContainer">
    <div class="leftColumn">
      <h1>Left Column</h1>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
      <h1>Right Column</h1>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have included a CodePen to show the problem: https://codepen.io/Macast/pen/ZaZrNz

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erase the floats (make no sense in a table) to fix the height problem. Then in the media query, change `display` to `block` for the container and to `inline-block` for the two inner elements:

```css
#pageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#pageContainer p {
  line-height: 10px;
}

.sectionContainer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.leftColumn {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #4F4F4F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rightColumn {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #000000;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .sectionContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .leftColumn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .rightColumn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pageContainer">
  <div class="sectionContainer">
    <div class="leftColumn">
      <h1>Left Column</h1>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
      <h1>Right Column</h1>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. This removes any excess white space when the display reduces to a mobile size. Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` instead of `display: table;` and `float: left;`. That will make the children have equal height.

```css
#pageContainer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #pageContainer p {
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    
    .sectionContainer {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .leftColumn {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        background-color: #4F4F4F;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .rightColumn {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        color: #000000;
        
    }
    
    @media all and (max-width: 768px) {    
        .sectionContainer {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .leftColumn {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .rightColumn {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="pageContainer">
  <div class="sectionContainer">
    <div class="leftColumn">
      <h1>Left Column</h1>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
      <h1>Right Column</h1>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works for desktop sites but not for mobile sites. However another answer has been submitted. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `height:100%` to both `sectionContainer` and `leftColumn` classes seems to fix it.

```css
#pageContainer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #pageContainer p {
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    
    .sectionContainer {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        height:100%;
    }
    
    .leftColumn {
        display: table-cell;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #4F4F4F;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        height:100%;
    }
    
    .rightColumn {
        display: table-cell;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        color: #000000;
        
    }
    
    @media all and (max-width: 768px) {    
        .sectionContainer {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .leftColumn {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .rightColumn {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="pageContainer">
  <div class="sectionContainer">
    <div class="leftColumn">
      <h1>Left Column</h1>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
      <p>Left Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
      <h1>Right Column</h1>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
      <p>Right Column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```